# Why do Daedalus and Yoroi not support multi account delegation?

Tags: wallet, staking

I am not programmer, but I am interested in development from user point of view.

I was looking for a way how to delegate to different pools from a single wallet and Adalite was the only wallet which supports this option.
I found also other users asking this question. Why is so little talked about this feature which could help mainly the smaller pools to get delegators when people will be able to divide their funds easily among several of them?

Comment: A better place to get the ball rolling on this issue would be the GitHub repo https://github.com/input-output-hk/daedalus/issues/1763

Answer (score 2):

It's coming, but it isn't high priority right now in face of critical features. You can just make multiple wallets using a wallet like [adalite.io](https://adalite.io/) till its possible.